# Exception handling when backend URL resource is not reachable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, exception

I have the below js function in my vue.js single file component, I want to try catch the exception when the URL requested by `axios.post` is not reachable. I have put the whole code in try block but I still don't get the alert I have put in the catch block.

**Updated** using .catch

```
deploySelected: function(){
    this.showStatus = true ;
    // animate open the status window.
    $("#status_update").animate({height: '500'})
    var url = "http://test-web-machine01.localsite.com:5060/scripts/request_deploy";

     axios.post(url)
    .then(response => {
        if (typeof response.data.reason != "undefined"){
            alert("Recieved Status: " + response.data.status + ",\nReason: " + response.data.reason);
        }
        var req_id = response.data.result.request_id;
        this.statusMessage = "Initiating deployment of Scripts for Request ID: " + req_id ;
    })
    .catch((err) => alert(err))

    console.log(url);
}
```

Comment: promises have a `.catch` method ... you don't need try/catch ... so `axios.post(url).then(your code).catch(err=>alert(err))` would be equivalent of what you got there

Comment: Oops, yes I changed the code to use .catch still it doesnt pop up alert message for error.

Comment: so, does it popup an alert even when there's an error?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this: `.catch((err) => alert(err))` thanks @Jaromanda